# phpでDBからデータ取得するスクリプトを作成したものの、実行するとエラーとなる

Tags: php, mysql

#### やりたいこと

以下スクリプトを実行し、 `http://localhost:8889/PhpApiLesson/apiDb.php` にアクセスすることでDBから情報をブラウザに表示したい。

スクリプト

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ApiLessonDatabase;charset=utf8";
$user = 'root';
$password = '*********';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$dbh -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = 'select * from ApiLesson;';

$stmt = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$stmt -> execute();

while (true) {
    $rec = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($rec === false) {
        break;
    }
    $arr[] = $rec;
}

echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

下記コマンドをターミナルで実行するとDBの内容を表示

```
(base) *******@MacBook PhpApiLesson % mysql -u root -p

Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 18
Server version: 8.1.0 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use ApiLessonDatabase
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> select * from ApiLesson;
```

#### 困っていること

`http://localhost:8889/PhpApiLesson/apiDb.php` にアクセスすると下記エラーが表示される。

```html
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhpApiLesson/apiDb.php:8
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhpApiLesson/apiDb.php(8): PDO-&gt;__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', Object(SensitiveParameterValue))
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhpApiLesson/apiDb.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
```

#### 試してみたこと

phpmyadminに入ってみたところ、DBの内容が表示されなかった。

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
```

とするとユーザー一覧は下記のように表示される。

```
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
| your_user        | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: ターミナルでMySQLに接続した後"select user,host from mysql.user;"を実行して結果を質問文に追加してみてください。

Comment: ご返信くださりありがとうございます。追記しました。

Comment: あとは$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost:8889;dbname=ApiLessonDatabase;charset=utf8";くらいしか思いつきません。